# Basic Java? Arguments of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm currently learning Java and attempting a basic program. I'd like to create a new array which is 1 size larger than my old array and make the arguments of the new array the same as the old array other than the last argument which I would like to define. What is currently wrong with my current code?  (I have defined q earlier in the code)

```
int p = c.length;
p++;
int[] d = new int[p];
for (int n=0; n<d.length-1; n++)
{
    d[n] = c[n];
}
d[d.length-1]=q;
```

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong?

Comment: I obtain the error:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: What's the length of the original array you are testing your code with?

Comment: c is the original array and d is the new array. c has length 1 less than d.

Comment: If I run this code, it works just fine for me.

Comment: This should be right. You must miss some information.

Comment: I'm unsure what this is?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me:

```
public class ArrayEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int length1 = arr1.length;
        length1++;
        int[] arr2 = new int[length1];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length - 1; i++) {
            arr2[i] = arr1[i];
        }

        arr2[arr2.length - 1] = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints

```
10
20
30
40
50
10
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I'm guessing some error on your part in some other place.

Comment: Very strange? So the out of bounds exception comes from somewhere else even though the error is on the line: arr2[i] = arr1[i]; ?

Comment: There is no reason as to why your code should have an error. Did you try to run my code? It's pretty basic, does exactly what you are doing, compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Yes I've tried to run the full code and obtain the error mentioned above?